# can we hide form fields depend on other fields?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

im trying to make the form that i'm creating dynamic as much as possible ,
so i have a case that if the user select value from dropDown list some fields will hide and other will appear , but i have other case when there are more then 2 dropDown list , let me give you guys example :

dropDown A :['a','b','c'],
dropDown B:['d','e','f'],

first case if the user select from A.a then the field `name` will appear and field `email` will hide .

second case if we have the first case and the user if select from B.e will appear some filed and other will hide .

so how i can do it , this is my code. but it's not working properly :

```
const [fieldsToHide, setFieldsToHide] = useState<string[]>([
    'name',
    'email',
    'password',
    'signIn',
    'signUp'
  ]);

const onFieldsChange = useCallback((changedFields: FieldData[], allFields: FieldData[]) => {
    const [changedField] = changedFields;
    const { name, value } = changedField || ({} as FieldData);
    if (Array.isArray(name) && name.length) {
      const [fieldName] = name;
      if (fieldName === 'A' && value === 'a') {
        setFieldsToHide(['name', 'email']);
      } else if (fieldName === 'A' && value === 'c') {
        setFieldsToHide(['email']);
      } else if (fieldName === 'A' && value === 'b') {
        setFieldsToHide(['name']);
      } else if (fieldName === 'B' && value === 'd') {
        setFieldsToHide(...fieldsToHide,'password']);
      } else if (fieldName === 'B' && value === 'e') {
        setFieldsToHide(...fieldsToHide,'signIn','signUp']);
      } 
    }
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not stated why it is not working. Where exactly you have a problem. One issue I can see is this:

```
setFieldsToHide(...fieldsToHide,['password'])
```

You execute here a function with multiple parameters - while you want to execute it with one parameter - one table:

```
setFieldsToHide([...fieldsToHide,'password']);
```

or even better:

```
setFieldsToHide(prevFieldsToHide => [...prevFieldsToHide,'password']);
```

Comment: my problem when i select from second dropDown B it hide all the fields , also when i select from dropDown A it show all the fields for second dropDown